# how to detect the notification bar is activated or not in android?

Tags: android, notifications

I'm not able to upload image file because of low reputation, please understand.

As you guys know, you can see "the quick setting buttons" on the notification bar when you swipe the display up to down in android.

What I want to know is that how to detect the notification bar is activated or not. (If it is possible, also I want to know which one is clicked on the quick setting panel, like setting, airplane mode, brightness, volume and etc).

Can anyone helps me out?

Thank you.

Comment: Check this for a working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53509108/how-to-detect-when-the-notification-system-bar-is-opened/53509109#53509109

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution myself, it's not the code that I'm looking for, but it does what I'm after perfectly.

In your Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // make ContentObserver so that you can detect changes of settings.
    SettingsContentObserver mSettingsContentObserver = new SettingsContentObserver(new Handler());

    // and registerContentObserver with right URI (in case of mine, I'm trying to catch the change of bluetooth status weather it is on or off.)
    this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Settings.System.getUriFor(Settings.System.BLUETOOTH_ON),true, mSettingsContentObserver);
}

public class SettingsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public SettingsContentObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
    }
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        //Write anything you want to do after the observer detect the changes.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth On",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```